# Adding menu in wordpress but it should not be a page

Tags: wordpress

I have used `add_menu_page()` which adds a menu and also creates a submenu with that name.

The syntax is:

```
add_menu_page($pagetitle,$menutitle,$capability,$menu_slug,$function,$icon-url,$position);
```

For example:

```
add_menu_page('ABCD','ABCD','read','r121_abcd','callMe','','4');
```

This creates a menu in my administration screen but it also creates a submenu with same name `ABCD`.

I don't want that name for my submenu I want it as `PQRST` or I don't want any page associated with that menu. And then I can add pages using `add_submenu_page()`.

So there should be `ABCD(Menu) -> PQRST(submenu)`. No `ABCD(menu) -> ABCD(submenu)`.

I am not able to figure out that .

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
add_menu_page('','ABCD','read','ABCD_slug','','','4');
add_submenu_page('ABCD_slug','PQRST','PQRST','read','ABCD_slug',array($this,'myFunction'));
remove_submenu_page('ABCD_slug', 'ABCD_slug');
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Format - > add_menu_page($pagetitle,$menutitle,$capability,$menu_slug,$function,$icon-url,$position);
add_menu_page('','ABCD','read','ABCD_slug','','','4');

//Format - >
add_submenu_page($parent_slug,$page_title,$menu_title,$capability,$menu_slug,$function);
add_submenu_page('ABCD_slug','PQRST','PQRST','read','ABCD_slug',array($this,'myFunction'));
```

This does the thing, i.e. giving the same menu_slug.